# What is the virtue of having true belief?

Tags: truth, virtue-ethics

What is the virtue of having a true belief: where can I read about it?

I have two specific questions, before reading about it (and I don't even know what we would call it, wisdom?)

1. Is that virtue intrinsically valuable, or is it just the virtues we associate with having true beliefs that are intrinsically valuable?
2. Is the intrinsic value of having a true belief only a matter of virtue?

Comment: are you looking for an objective answer or subjective?

Comment: I am looking for any answer that you can ground in philosophical literature, especially analytic @NikosM. I suppose that means "not subjective"?

Comment: does [knowledge as justified true belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#KnowJustTrueBeli) count?

Comment: no that doesn't address my question, but thanks @NikosM. I could try asking again subbing "knowledge" for "true belief" but it interests me less

Comment: [Sosa, Virtue Epistemology: Apt Belief and Reflective Knowledge](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/a-virtue-epistemology-apt-belief-and-reflective-knowledge-volume-1/).

Comment: See also related thread [What is the axiological basis of the preference of truth to falsity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/76299/9148) To quote from Peirce:"*It is those facts that I want to know, so that I may avoid disappointments and disasters. Since they are bound to press upon me at last, let me know them as soon as possible, and prepare for them. This is, in the last analysis, my whole motive in reasoning.*"

Comment: Leaving aside the mapping between true belief and actual knowledge of truth, for a minute, and Conifold's references, a true belief has virtue in itself, in that it is compatible both to objectives and actions. Thus minimizes internal conflict, between what I do and what I want to achieve. I am not aware of any references on this at this point, but I might come back

Comment: There is plenty of disutility in having false beliefs. If you believe you can fly and throw yourself off a cliff, that's bad. If you believe homeopathic medicines can cure your cancer, that's bad. If you believe politicians can make the world a better place, that's bad.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “true belief”: Believing something that is true, or being a true believer?