# Are there famous unsolved problems in logic akin to the Millenium Prize problems?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, symbolic-logic

Are there major theorems that logicians have yet to tackle? And I don't mean any problems that pertain to the philosophy of logic (i.e. logical pluralism, the nature of logical consequence, etc), but straight up meta-logical theorems about particular logics.

Comment: See [What are some important but still unsolved problems in mathematical logic? on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/227083/51484) and an existing [analog on PhilSE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/51372/9148). Wikipedia has [another list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Model_theory_and_formal_languages). One of them is one of the Millenium problems: is [Boolean satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) solvable in polynomial time, i.e. does NP=P?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical logic is definitely still an active field. Exactly what constitutes "meta-logical theorems about particular logics" is a bit unclear, but according to any reasonable interpretation I can think of there are plenty of major open questions under this heading. Here are just a couple:

- [**Vaught's conjecture**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaught_conjecture) about the number of (countable) models (up to isomorphism) of a (countable, consistent, complete, first order) theory is perhaps the oldest "major" open question in mathematical logic. It's a question about the basic set-theoretic properties of the semantics of first-order logic, so I'd think it would qualify.
- The subfield of [**abstract model theory**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263) is full of questions about logics stronger than first-order, including general existence questions (e.g. "Is there a logic, appropriately defined, which has the compactness and interpolation properties?"). Abstract model theory is no longer as active as it once was, but that's not because all the questions got answered - rather, it's because the questions turned out to be *really really hard*.
- Fragments of first-order logic, and nonclassical propositional logics, play important roles in theoretical computer science and complexity theory, and there are plenty of open questions around their combinatorial properties (e.g. about the [lengths of proofs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03691.pdf) in propositional systems of various kinds).
- Finally, via finite model theory we can often reformulate complexity-theoretic questions like P vs. NP as questions about the relationship between different logics on finite structures; this is called [**descriptive complexity theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory). And again, there are plenty of open questions here (including a rephrasing of P vs. NP as hinted at in the previous sentence).

More generally, [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/227083/51484) which Conifold's comment above mentioned has a lot of relevant information.